# Problem with Streamlit session_state on ranged slider

Tags: python, slider, session-state, streamlit

I'm trying to implement a ranged slider in my streamlit app. It should define which content to show below on the website. More accurately, I want to show texts which are stored with a "date" value, showing, when to publish this specific text. I'm querying my SQL database to define the range the slider should present as min_value and max_ value. But when using the slider, the default values get reestablished after the apps rerun.

Im starting with the following SQL query:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT MIN(scheduled_pub) FROM tbl_article;"
cursor.execute(query)
oldest_date = cursor.fetchone()[0]
cursor.close()
    
today = datetime.now()
```

Now i'm handing these two dates over as parameters to my ranged slider, by default showing every date from my first database entry up to today.

```
range_selected = st.slider(label="range",
                           min_value=oldest_date,
                           max_value=today,
                           value=(oldest_date, today))
```

When running the app the slider shows up as intended, but as soon as I change one of the two values, the app gets rerun and resets the value to default. I assume that's because the SQL query gets processed again and the variables are set to those values again.
I'm aware of the session_state fucntionality, but I can't quite get my head around it. All the documentation and tutorials are showing how to use session_state with buttons. I tried several ways of declaring the `if "range" not in session_state:` and other code snippets i found somewhere, but I was not able to get the app running as intended and it drives me crazy. I get what the session_state does, it stores a value even after a rerun. But I don't understand the syntax and how to declare what to save and in which case.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried several ways of declaring the if "range" not in session_state: and other code snippets i found somewhere, but I was not able to get the app running as intended and it drives me crazy. I get what the session_state does, it stores a value even after a rerun. But I don't understand the syntax and how to declare what to save and in which case.

The `if` statement is how you would initialize the session state value at the beginning of the script – e.g.:

```
if "range" not in st.session_state:
   st.session_state.range = <your desired default value>
```

To update the value of `range` later in the script, you can use the following syntax:

```
st.session_state.range = <your desired range value>
```

You can also use this syntax:

```
st.session_state['range'] = <your desired range value>
```